# Get "most recent" start date, and "most recent" end date in row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have data with 3 columns fields, `start date`, `finish date` and `progress`.

Users Report Example:

| Start Date | End Date | Progress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | 01/13/2022 | 20 |

Users append to this file adding these three columns over and over.

So 1 row contains nth columns.

For example of an "appended report"

The first 3 columns are user 1, the next 3 columns are user 2

| Start Date | End Date | Progress | Start Date | End Date | Progress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | 01/13/2022 | 20 | 01/11/2022 | 01/12/2022 | 20 |

Before all these "reporting" columns there is 2 summary columns

| Last Reported Start Date | Last Reported End Date | etc.... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/2022 | 01/12/2022 | etc... |

I need the `last reported start date` to match the right-most date entered under the `start date`.

I need the `last reported end date` to match the right-most date entered under the `end date`.

**Note that start dates, and/or end dates may be missing**
In which case it checks the next column to the left...So, look for a date, within this row starting from the right, irrespective if its the max or min date.

This SORT OF works

`IFNA(LOOKUP(2,1/($P15:$AAZ15>D15),$P15:$AAZ15),[@[Planned Start Date]])`

But it isn't smart enough to only use `start date` in `Last Reported start date` and only use `end date` for `last reported end date`

Using the example above I end up with the result of

| Last Reported Start Date | Last Reported End Date | etc.... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | 01/12/2022 | etc... |

The complete report appears as

| Last Reported Start Date | Last Reported End Date | Start Date | End Date | Progress | Start Date | End Date | Progress | Start Date | End Date | Progress | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | 01/09/2022 | 01/12/2022 | - | 20 | - | 01/21/2022 | 5 | - | 1/09/2022 | 50 | etc |

Take note that the two days I would want here are the Only start date specified (in this case its 01/12/2022) and then (because theres multiple end dates) the right most end date (which is 01/09/2022)

Comment: For excel 365 you should be able to use `Max(Filter())`, that is as long as all of the columns are standardize, but you mention people are filling in columns which may make it not the case...

Comment: The Number of columns per report is standard (3) but the sheet grows every day (by 3 columns at a time). and we're still using 2016 and don't have the filter() function :(

ALso max won't work because, its not always the "max date" sometimes the "last date" is less than the rows "max" date.

Comment: I think for excel 2016 it's something like `index(match())`, but search for something like return all colunns based on criteria. After that it is taking the `max`. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: I've clarified the post. @gns100, we can't use max date as the "last reported date" may be less than the rest of rows "max" data point.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have data being input 9 columns a day. Each entry has 3 sets of data in it and each set of data includes `Start Date`, `End Date`, and `Progress`. Not all those fields will be filled in. That means you may have a row like this:

[image: Data Example]

You want to extract the `Start Date` and `End Date` values that are the furthest to the right even if they aren't the maximum values entered in that row. You can pull the `Start Date` like this:

```
=INDEX(2:2,MAX(IF(($1:$1="Start Date")*(2:2>0),COLUMN(2:2))))
```

- `INDEX(2:2,` because we're going to pull some value from row 2. You don't have to reference the entire row (here or elsewhere) but it makes it where your formula keeps working as the data keeps growing.
- `($1:$1="Start Date")*(2:2>0)` is way of using `AND` except for arrays. When you force TRUE/FALSE values to do math, they become 1/0 values instead. However, if it's looking for TRUE/FALSE values and you give it 1/0 values, it's still quite happy. This will be an array of TRUE/FALSE where it is is only TRU if both the text in the first row is "Start Date" and the value in this row is not 0. Unless you think someone is going to enter 1/0/1900 as a date, this will be fine. You can also check for not equal to blank, but this works.
- `IF((~)*(~),COLUMN(2:2))` will return either the column number (when those two conditions are true) or FALSE (which is treated like 0).
- `MAX(IF((~)*(~),COLUMN(2:2)))`, then, will find the highest column number where both those things are true.
- `INDEX(2:2,MAX())` will pull the values from row 2 that is the last column where both those conditions are true.

For `End Date`, you can do something very similar:

```
=INDEX(2:2,MAX(IF(($1:$1="End Date")*(2:2>0),COLUMN(2:2))))
```

... or, if you think someone may enter a start date without also entering an end date and you want to grab whatever value is to the right of the last start date:

```
=INDEX(2:2,MAX(IF(($1:$1="Start Date")*(2:2>0),COLUMN(2:2)))+1)
```

---

Note: `2:2` is relative but `$1:$1` is absolute. This allows you to put the formula in row 2 and then copy it down to update the row reference but not the header row reference.

Comment: You have the requirements exactly right.   

Get date furthest to the right even if they aren't the maximum values entered in that row

Someone may enter a start date without also entering an end date (or vice versa)


I remocked up what you did (as i couldn't get it working) and it doesn't output as I might have expected.

Not sure how to attach images, but here is the mock up data
https://imgur.com/k40XyiH 

Output of the three lines
https://imgur.com/JFyAH4r

Comment: @Patrick If you used a specific range instead of the whole row, you'll need to adjust the value fed into the `INDEX` because you're pulling `COLUMN()` regardless of the smaller range. I would recommend keeping `=INDEX(2:2,` the same and then it won't be a problem.